# Getting error "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" on Firefox version 37

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Firefox version 37 so that I can use Firepath, But now when I run my java  scripts I am getting error "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities". I am finding online solutions which are saying to upgrade the Firefox, but I do not want to upgrade , Please help me to find an alternate solution other than "upgrading" Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-and-python)

Comment: At that link, Code is given for python language, I want the code for java.

Comment: I got the solution, Put this code in your program : System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "false");

Comment: Yeah, But my answer is in java language  and more easy to understand for java developers.