# Selenium webdriver exception in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python3 in kali linux 2018.3,selenium 3.13 and firefox61,geckodriver21, i dowloaded the geckodriver and added it to my path, after running the code i get this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


def main():

    try:
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
        usr_input = "jackets"
        element.send_keys(usr_input)
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nav-search-submit .nav-input').click()
        driver.close()
    except TimeoutError:
        print("fail")
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

i tried the same with chrome and it worked just fine.

Comment: i tried the answer in this link but it didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a

Comment: Which line are you getting this error at?

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace please